# Get Quick Tile which was long-pressed from ACTION_QS_TILE_PREFERENCES

Tags: android

I have more than one Quick tile in my app, which all do different things. The issue I'm facing is that I want all of my quick tiles to have a long-press action to configure specific settings regarding that tile, so I've added the `android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE_PREFERENCES` in an intent-filter which goes to an activity.

The problem is that there seems to be no way of knowing which tile was long-pressed, just that a tile was in fact long-pressed.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService#ACTION_QS_TILE_PREFERENCES) there should maybe be a way to solve this where

> This intent may also define a Intent.EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME value to indicate the ComponentName that caused the preferences to be opened.

I assumed this would return the class which implements `TileService`, but calling `intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME)` doesn't give anything at all.

Am I misinterpreting the documentation? What should this `Intent.EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME` give? Is there any way to identify which tile was long-pressed?

Answer (score 2):

`EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME` points to a `ComponentName` object, not a String.

Therefore you need to use `getParcelableExtra()` to extract the `ComponentName` object:

```
ComponentName qsTile = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME);
```

Comment: It still returns null. I forgot to add that this is xamarin though, but that shouldn't have any effect from what I've gathered.

Comment: It is working fine here. Maybe try it with a small sample app just to confirm it is working for you.

Comment: Working fine on my emulators (API 24 and 29). On my Huawei P20 Pro with Android 9.1 however, the ComponentName is always null as well.